# Git: Efficient steps to create a new branch and push to remote

Tags: git, bitbucket

I figured out the steps but seems cumbersome, take `bitbucket` for example, suppose i already have a project called `prj`

1. I branch a new project from server side(bitbucket.com), called `prj-bz`
2. From local i add add a remote `git remote add prj-bz https://blah...`
3. At the same time from local i create a new branch called `prj-bz`
4. From local i call `git push prj-bz prj-bz` to let local repo and remote one connected.

I checked out some git books but seem none cover this.
Any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: no, there is no efficient way of doing this. How do you think this can be more efficient?

Comment: Maybe the first step can be omitted?

Comment: Oh, I think I understood that wrong. In the 1 step, you mean you create a branch on bitbucket?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Generally, people usually do one or the other **Fork** or **Branch**. It sounds like you are making a Fork of a repo, then making a branch in the fork with the same name. If you're using a Pull Request to put data back in to the main repo, you don't need to do both. Pick one of the two workflows:

- Fork the repo on Bitbucket (or other site)
- Clone the repo `git clone https://bitbucket.org/username/repo-fork.git`
- Work in that fork `git commit -m "some work done"`, `git push -u origin master`
- Create a Pull request to request your changes to be placed back into the parent of the fork

OR

- Clone the main repo `git clone https://bitbucket.org/username/repo-fork.git`
- Create a new local branch `git checkout -b my-branch`
- Work in that branch `git commit -m "some work done"`
- Push up the *branch* `git push -u origin my-branch`
- Create a Pull request

With the branch method, I'm assuming you have rights to write to the main repo. If not, you'll want to stick to the fork method. There are more workflows out there too. Bitbucket also has a [doc explaining this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Branch+or+Fork+Your+Repository) as well as one on [Atlassian's website](http://atlassian.com/git/workflows) with a bit more depth on Git workflows.

Comment: Thank you Marcus, i use the **Branch** method you mentioned, and it worked perfectly well.

Comment: `git push -u origin my-branch` is the most important step here

Answer (score 2):

For creating new branch we will use:
(using this command A new branch will create and the branch status will also change with newly created branch)

```
git checkout -b branch-name
```

And for pushing the changes we can run following commands:

```
git add . 
git commit -m "with meaningful comments" 
git push origin branch-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if creating a new repo instead of a new branch in an existing one, you could just `git clone https://blah <target folder>` to replace steps 2-4.

If not, your only real alternative is creating a simple script that accepts remote name, branch name and git url as arguments and executes steps 2-4 with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps to create a 'dev' or 'prj-bz' branch and save all changes,

**Step 1:** Create a dev branch to save development changes,

```
git checkout -b dev
git add .
git commit -m “Your commit message”
git push -u origin dev
```

**Step 2:** Do all development and whenever you need to push changes on the dev branch,

```
git add .
git commit -m “Your commit message”
git push origin dev
```

**Step 3:** Merge changes from dev to main whenever changes are final for production,

```
git push origin dev
git checkout main
git merge dev
git push origin main
```

**Step 4:** Once merge is done, go back to the dev branch and do all development and repeat Step-2,

```
git checkout dev
```