# I want to push to a branch which is not master. That is what I did

Tags: git

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first"
git push origin ritu
```

(second is the name of a branch) but it say

```
fatal: origin does not appear to be a git repository.
fatal: could not read from remote repository.
Please sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: What is the output of `git brnach` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: Efficient steps to create a new branch and push to remote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131864/git-efficient-steps-to-create-a-new-branch-and-push-to-remote)

Comment: You didn't set the origin anywhere. Origin is the original repo where you cloned from. Since you just created the repo, you have no other origin, thus you can't push.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git set upstream to origin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917459/git-set-upstream-to-origin)

Comment: @RohanSarkar: what do you want to do with your `git push` command ?

Answer (score 7):

You have to add the remote first, and you probably also want to create a local branch first, so in full:

```
git init
git remote add origin <url>

# or, instead if init+remote:  git clone <url>

git add ...
git commit
git branch ritu
git push origin ritu
```

Answer (score 2):

`git init` will only create a *local* repository.

You have not defined any link to a *remote* copy, and `git push` will not work.

Depending on what you need :

1. you only want to keep a local history of your project : you do not need to use any remote copies, and you can just ignore the `git push` step.
2. you want to share this project with other people : you will need to create a remote repository accessible to these other people.
3. your intention is to work on an existing project : you should start by cloning this existing project, and find some way to move your work on this clone.

---

You generally get a repository with a remote copy when you start out by *cloning* a existing repository, e.g :

```
# this will create a local 'project/' repository,
# with all the history of the remote project,
# and, by default, git will keep the information :
#     "'origin' is a shortcut for https://github.com/user/project"

git clone https://github.com/user/project
```

Answer (score 0):

Before pushing it to remote you need to add one. You can achieve this by `git remote add origin git@host_name:user_name/repo.git`

Once you have done this, try `git push -u origin your_branch`